# Using PYQT drawing function in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, map-drawing

I work on a wood fire simulator project in university that uses QGIS.
I have to draw various symbols on the map.

As I'm not able to design it with qgis functions so I made it with in a stand alone python program using PYQT5 like that:

[image]

Can I use my PYQT drawing functions in QGIS?

Comment: You should be able to use the Plugins/Python Console to test your code.  Click on the small "Show Editor" and you can load external code.   Or you could look at the Plugin Builder  https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html  Is the Python Builder or you can import your code in the Plugins/Python Console.   Click on the little "Show Editor" and you should be able to open your .py file or test a block of code by clicking the "+" icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm working in a similar area and would recommend you to create styles of lines in Qgis, save them as qml files and use those files to render features in your PyQgis app.
[image: Handling styles in Qgis]

As you can see from the picture my style of line is very similar to yours.
In your standalone application, you can assign qml as follows

```
some_layer.loadNamedStyle(qml_file_name)
```

And if you wish your way you should look into qml format and create it from your application in order to use it in Qgis.

Access to Qgis style generator. I mean Qgis 3.2.3 Bonn
1. After you opened Qgis, follow items of menus: Layer-> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer
[image: Open layer]

2. Supposing you opened layer Test_line and drew a polyline in it.
   [image: Polyline]
3. Click right button mouse and choose Properties in the drop-down menu
   [image: Drop-down menu]
4. Layer Properties dialog will appear where you should select the Symbology tab on the left side of the dialog
   [image: Layer Properties]
5. Using the dialog you change color and width of the line (black and 0.26 in my case)
6. Add symbol layer with the help of a plus button
   [image: Add symbol layer]
7. Change Symbol layer type to Marker line
   [image: Marker line]
8. Change Simple Marker to a triangle and its color to black
   [image: Simple marker]
9. Select Simple line and change its offset to 1.0 and you'll get the desired style
   [image: The style]
10. And on the map
    [image: Map]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that I have to make a stand alone program using QGIS as a package and not a script I add to QGIS.

Comment: Actually, I meant exactly the same. I talked about how to use Qgis style generator in a pyqgis standalone application.

Comment: Sorry I misread sometimes (English isn't my mother tongue). So How do I access the Qgis style generator? I tried but I can't find it.

Comment: Look at the answer again, I've tried to explain how to get the style you showed in your question.

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot! I still have a question: which kind of layer am I supposed to use for this?

Comment: In QGIS select menu items as follows. Layer->Create Layer->New Shapefile layer. Then in the dialog New Shapefile Layer you should specify 'Geometry type' Line.

Comment: I meant in my stand alone application: for the some_layer.loadNamedStyle(qml_file_name)            instruction

Comment: from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer; some_layer = QgsVectorLayer(path2shapeFile, "boundary", "ogr")

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your original question: "Can I use my PYQT drawing functions in QGIS" - the answer is yes!

You'd need to subclass the `QgsLineSymbolLayer` class, adding your custom drawing code inside the `renderPolyline` method. There's a good guide for how to do this at https://hub.packtpub.com/how-vector-features-are-displayed/ . Unfortunately it's for QGIS 2.18, so you'd need to adopt the API a little for use in QGIS 3 (mostly removal of the "V2" suffixes on the class names).